# How do I correctly configure OpenEMM on my CentOS server?

Tags: centos, email-server

I am currently running a CentOS server (the most recent version) and followed the OpenEMM installation guide to install OpenEMM 2013. I updated my Java and Tomcat. Upon finishing the installation I use the following commands:

```
su openemm
/home/openemm/bin/openemm.sh start
```

I am getting two failed messages:

```
Starting sendmails:    listener Starting sendmail: 451 4.0.0 can not chdir(/var/spool/mqueue/):  Permission denied
Program mode requires special privileges, e.g., root or TrustedUser.
```

And

```
Starting sm-client: touch : cannot touch '/var/run/sm-client.pid': Permission denied
chown: cannot access '/var/run/sm-client.pid': No such file or directory
lstat(/var/run/sm-client.pid) failed: no such file or directory
Permission denied (real uid not trusted)
```

After these [FAILED] responses Starting up Tomcat and the Java checks seem to run okay with no problems.

I have changed the Trusted User privileges to

```
O TrustedUser=openemm
```

However, that does not seem to clear the error messages.

If I attempt to go to the server destination path in my web browser I don't get anywhere with the URL or the IP Address even with the port 8080 at the end of it like OpenEMM suggests.

I am wondering if I have this configured incorrectly. Can anyone suggest some ideas to try to fix these errors and/or get my web address to correctly display OpenEMM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I had the command:

```
su openemm
```

And needed  su - openemm . Among that problem the other issue I was having was I had the wrong version of Java installed and setup incorrectly. Which is the reason that  I could not my browser to display OpenEMM.

I have reinstalled Java and reconfigured my setup. Seems to be going smoothly now.